# Distinct/GroupBy in WhenAll result Async

Tags: linq, asynchronous, lambda, async-await, task

I am writing a method in which i am using async prog.

```
 var tasks = new List<Task<List<SomeClass>>>();

 tasks.Add(this.Method1());
 tasks.Add(this.Method2());
 var results = await Task.WhenAll(tasks).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

i want distinct records from this result. How to achieve that.
currently i have written

```
  return results.SelectMany(s => s).GroupBy(x => x.Name).Select(x => x.FirstOrDefault()).ToList();
```

But i am not sure with SelectMany,  will this give correct result.

Comment: Well, what is `results`? And isn't it easy to check if the results are correct?

Answer (score 0):

`SelectMany(s => s)` is a "flatten" operation. It takes a sequence of sequences and flattens them to a single sequence.

The LINQ "distinct" operator is called [`Distinct`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.distinct?view=netframework-4.8#overloads). If your `SomeClass` overrides equality to be based on `Name`, then that's all you need:

```
return results.SelectMany(s => s).Distinct().ToList();
```

But if `SomeClass` doesn't define equality that way, you'll need to do another kind of distinct.

One option is to use [the `Distinct` overload that takes an equality comparer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.distinct?view=netframework-4.8#System_Linq_Enumerable_Distinct__1_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Collections_Generic_IEqualityComparer___0__). Then you can pass in an equality comparer that determines equality by `Name`. To do this, first define an equality comparer:

```
public sealed class NameEqualityComparer: IEqualityComparer<SomeClass>
{
  public int GetHashCode(SomeClass obj) => EqualityComparer<string>.Default.GetHashCode(obj.Name);
  public bool Equals(SomeClass x, SomeClass y) => EqualityComparer<string>.Default.Equals(x.Name, y.Name);
}
```

and then you can invoke the correct overload:

```
return results.SelectMany(s => s).Distinct(new NameEqualityComparer()).ToList();
```

I have a [library](https://github.com/StephenCleary/Comparers) that helps define custom comparers (properly handling all edge cases), which I prefer to use for things like this. With the Nito.Comparers library, you don't need to define a custom `NameEqualityComparer`; instead, you can define comparers in-line like this:

```
return results.SelectMany(s => s).Distinct(b => b.EquateBy(x => x.Name)).ToList();
```

or separately, if desired:

```
var comparer = EqualityComparerBuilder.For<SomeClass>().EquateBy(x => x.Name);
return results.SelectMany(s => s).Distinct(comparer).ToList();
```

A completely different option is to add a new "Distinct-By" operator that acts the way you want. This is part of [MoreLINQ](https://morelinq.github.io/) or you can add it yourself:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> DistinctBy<T, TKey>(this IEnumerable<T> @this, Func<T, TKey> selector)
{
  var keys = new HashSet<TKey>();
  foreach (var item in @this)
  {
    if (keys.Add(selector(item)))
      yield return item;
  }
}
```

Then you can use the new operator like this:

```
return results.SelectMany(s => s).DistinctBy(x => x.Name).ToList();
```

All of these options are more efficient than grouping.